# Using the __format__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written up a mock method to test the usage of `__format__`. For example:

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self, name='tom', age=25):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        if format_spec == "age":
            return f'{self.name.capitalize()} is {self.age} years old.'
        elif format_spec == 'name':
            return f'The name of the person of this instance is {self.name.capitalize()}'

>>> n=Name()
>>> format(n, 'age')
'Tom is 25 years old.'
```

Is this a legitimate example of how the `__format__` method might be used? That is, to pass a "human-readable" type of `format_spec`? Or is this method supposed to received input such as `"+,.4f"`. I haven't seen too many real-world examples of the `__format__` method being used, so am curious what some non-trivial examples might be.

Comment: It would be very unusual for `__format__` to provide completely different information depending on the format spec. As the name implies, it's usually just supposed to control the format in which information is presented.

Comment: @user2357112 could you please explain what you mean by "different information depending on the format spec" ? Do you mean the format spec provided by python, for example in https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? [`object.__format__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__)

Comment: Your `__format__` provides age information in one case, and name information in another case. That's very unusual.